# Inject Instance<Interface> : Spring and CDI compatibility

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, cdi

I am wondering how can I use the [Instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html) in JUnit4 with Spring

```
@Inject
Instance<IMyInterface> interfaces;
```

If I use

```
@Inject
List<IMyInterface> interfaces;
```

It works in Spring but not with CDI.
Also, we can use [Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html) with both CDI and Spring but it's not Iterable.

Comment: I meant in JUnit4 with Spring (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner). I've edited my post.

Comment: Explain when down voting please

Answer (score 0):

The `@Inject` annotation comes from JSR-330-Dependency Injection for Java. Spring knows this annotation and briefly said, Spring treats it as an alternative to `@Autowired`. That's it.

However, the Instance is part of JSR 299 - Contexts & Dependency Injection. You can have a look at the [definition](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#dynamic_lookup) in CDI specifications.

Spring DI is absolutely different and does not implement JSR-299 (CDI) or any other standard. It does not even have a separate API and implementations and everything is just glued together. Therefore, injecting an Instace is **not possible** with Spring.

Comment: So there is no workaround except injecting all classes one by one using @Inject?

Comment: When Spring core is used, then there is no official way. There are some projects that may help you: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DeltaSpike/Spring+CDI+integration

https://github.com/matzew/spring-cdi-bridge