# Getting UnsatisfiedDependencyException: while using JSF @Push-annotation with Spring frame work

Tags: java, spring, jsf, cdi, jsf-2.3

Trying to Migrate from Primefaces PUSH to JSF Push(Websocket),
While trying out JSF Push in Java project JSF Push works fine as expected.

But when trying in Spring application I'm getting the below exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'pushBean': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clock'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.faces.push.PushContext' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject(), @javax.faces.push.Push(channel=clock)}
```

Project structure looks like this.

[Project-Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUsoM.jpg)

Below is my xml configs

**applicationContext.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javatpoint" />

</beans>
```

**beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.ENABLE_WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.ENABLE_CDI_RESOLVER_CHAIN</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param> 

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
      </listener>
      <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
      </listener> 

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**PushBean.class**

```
@Component
public class PushBean implements Serializable
{
    @Inject
    @Push(channel = "clock")
    private PushContext clock;

    public void clockAction()
    {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        String time = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + now.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        clock.send(time);
    }
}
```

Please suggest whether I'm missing any configurations in order to resole this issue and get JSF Push working?

Answer (score 0):

This post might be helpful. 
Spring does not recognize the @Push annotation as a qualifier 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50097928/4519750